# Android Material Date Picker Pick Multiple Dates for example 4 Dates from the Same Calendar

Tags: android, android-studio, datepicker, materialdatepicker

I would like to pick one, two, three or more dates from a Calendar in an android studio, how can i implement that using Material Date Picker or the normal date picker and get all the selected dates from the calendar

Below is the code for my Material Date Picker

```
MaterialDatePicker.Builder builder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker();

        builder.setTitleText("Select date range of publication");

        // If you want to set theme here
        //builder.setTheme(R.style.MaterialTheme);

        MaterialDatePicker<Long> materialDatePicker = builder.build();

        materialDatePicker.show(getParentFragmentManager(),"DATE_PICKER");

        materialDatePicker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener(selection -> {

            etDatesToPublish.setText(materialDatePicker.getHeaderText());

        });
```